# Reserved outbound ip addresses for Azure websites

Tags: azure, ip, azure-web-app-service

Currently creating websites in Azure and was wondering if there was a way to create reserved static outbound ip addresses for those websites. I am not creating and loading the websites via virtual machines or cloud services, just directly through the Azure websites option in the Azure portal. I read that by default, a virtual ip per region for your subscription is supplied but We don't want to provide this ip address to whitelist. Can anyone please help point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Given Azure Websites is a multi-tenant environment, the outbound IP address is shared by multiple customers. I believe you need to use a different way how to secure your endpoint (password/token/client cert) and use the whitelisting just as a defense in depth protection (but not as a primary one). If you really need to do an IP acling, then you can do a setup with some proxy which does the authentication (using a different method) and then whitelist an IP address of that proxy. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with Microsoft Azure.

The outbound IP will be one of the IPs in the datacenter. The list of IPs in the datacenter can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn175718.aspx).

The good news is that Microsoft are planning to make this feature available [soon.](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6722199-dedicated-reserved-outbound-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

Now its possible!!!
you can use App Service Environment(ASE)

> App Service supports dedicated outbound IP addresses for apps deployed using the App Service Environment (ASE) feature.
>
> For the forseeable future, apps running in the public multi-tenant service will continue to use outbound addresses from a shared address pool.

from [Dedicate outbound ip](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6722199-dedicated-reserved-outbound-ip-address)

ASE is very costly :)